# reordering of on-screen numeric keyboard

Tags: css

This is regarding an HTML full screen application that occasionally has need of numeric entry.

For some size devices, I would like an on-screen numeric keyboard to look like:

```
7 8 9
4 5 6
3 2 1
0 Reset
```

For other size devices, I would like the on-screen numeric keyboard to look like:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
Reset
```

Each digit and the word reset would be  (various values as shown). Can I do this reordering with media queries and CSS3, and only one set of buttons, or (the only way I have figured out so far) must I have two sets of buttons in the different orders, and display one or the other based on the media query?

Comment: You could always use absolute positioning (Note that even though it is absolute doesn't mean it can't be percentage-based). Grid layout would work really nicely for this, but there is minimal browser support at this point.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Hadn't thought of that... will have to play and see whether that is more or less complex, overall, than displaying only one of two keyboards. Thanks. Not sure how grid would help?

Comment: Grid layout lets you specify (in CSS) the [row and column](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid-row-column/) of each item in the grid. You could specify this inside media queries. Unfortunately only IE supports it at this time.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Sounds cool. Sounds tomorrow :) Thanks for the info.